# @EnableJpaRepositories/@EntityScan annotations mandatory in spring data jpa configuration setup?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I was going through this tutorial where the instructor was configuring `Spring Data JPA`. He had created the *Entity classes* and *Repository interfaces* and then added the `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` annotations on the main application as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.test.controller", "com.test.services"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.repository")
@EntityScan("com.test.entity")
public class MainApplication{
    public static void main(String args[]){
         SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args[]);
    }
}
```

I was creating the same project on the side, which had the same *Entity classes* and *Repository interfaces* but my main application didn't have these annotations. Instead, I added only `@SpringBootApplication`. Despite the absence of the said annotations, I found the code to be working well and fetching data from the db without issues. So my question is, what is the advantage of adding these annotations to the code ? Is it just for specifying the package where you can find the corresponding files, or are there any other advantages ?

Comment: These annotations are used in the early version of spring boot. In recent versions as long spring beans are available in the spring container it will inject these objects at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Spring searches for entities and repos in package where you placed your main class (and below this package). For example having these packages:

> java 
> -com 
> ---pack1 
> -----AnyEntity.java 
> ---pack2 
> -----Main.java

Spring won't be able to find AnyEntity automatically. In this situation you need to specify where the entity is using @EntityScan. When it comes to repositories, you deal with it similarly using @EnableJpaRepositories.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. Because in the project setup I created, I added in the Entity classes and annotated it with '@Entity' and it got picked up. I specifically skipped adding both '@EntityScan' and '@EnableJpaRepositories'. But the entities and repositories were configured and db transactions went through without problems.

Comment: But where did you add Entity classes? If you have placed it in the same package as main class, all db transactoins will be working fine without adding any other annotations. Can you show your package structure?

Comment: Yes. I've added the entity classes under the same package structure already which is why it is getting picked up.